# Asymptotic expansion of tanh at infinity?

Tags: asymptotics, power-series

Does $\tanh(x)$ have an asymptotic expansion for $x \rightarrow \infty$?

Comment: Well, since $\tanh\frac1{x}$ doesn't seem to have a Maclaurin series expansion... have a look at [these](http://functions.wolfram.com/ElementaryFunctions/Tanh/06/04/) though.

Comment: The natural estimates use $$\tanh x=(1-e^{-2x})(1-e^{-2x}+e^{-4x}-e^{-6x}+\cdots).$$

Comment: I guess what I meant was does it have an expansion in terms of powers of x?  Perhaps I should edit my question.

Comment: Then my first comment applies. Since $\exp\frac1{x}$ has an essential singularity at $x=0$, an asymptotic expansion of the form $c_0+\frac{c_1}{x}+\frac{c_2}{x^2}+\dots$ can't be done.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Write

$$\tanh(x) = \frac{1-e^{-2x}}{1+e^{-2x}}$$

Then you get an asymptotic expansion with powers of $e^{-2x}$ (which goes to $0$ as $x$ goes to infinity). It starts as

$$\tanh(x) = 1 - 2 e^{-2x} + o(e^{-2x})$$

There is no asymptotic expansion with powers of $x$ as that would imply that $e^{-x}$ has one (remember we're talking about asymptotic expansion when $x$ goes to infinity).

Comment: Re your last argument: simply, $\tanh(x)=1+o(x^{-n})$ for every $n$.

Comment: You're absolutely right. I guess I should have said instead that although there's an expansion with powers of $x$, it's a very rough approximation compared to the one with powers of $e^{-2x}$ (because $e^{-x}$ is so much smaller than any power of $x$).

Comment: @Didier Piau:  Your comment answered the question I meant to ask.  Thanks.

Comment: @Keith: Glad to help.

Answer (score 13):

Using the definition of $\tanh(x)$,
$$
\begin{align}
\tanh(x)&=\frac{e^x-e^{-x}}{e^x+e^{-x}}\\
&=\frac{1-e^{-2x}}{1+e^{-2x}}\\
&=\frac{2}{1+e^{-2x}}-1\\
&=1-2e^{-2x}+2e^{-4x}-2e^{-6x}+2e^{-8x}-\dots
\end{align}
$$
This converges to $\tanh(x)$ for all $x>0$. It also describes how $\tanh(x)$ behaves as $x\to\infty$.

Answer (score 0):

After a few tests, I've found that $\tanh(x) \approx 1 -1/x^5$ works very well for $x \gg 3$. I hope this can be useful. This resembles Pade approximation...